# Memory Warning Level Indicator - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, debugging, memory-management, warnings

I am using a ton of timers that update images in my game, and whenever I run it, the debugger somehow gives me a memory warning indicator level. I try adding some timers through a background thread, but that made a very small difference. Is there anyway I can reduce the memory usage of my app without having to get rid of my timers?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Are you sure the timers are responsible for the memory usage? Have you run your app using Instruments to see what objects are consuming the most memory?

Comment: How would I do that? What type of instruments? This is the first time this has happened to me, so I'm kind of new to it.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode, select from the menus: Run -> Run with Performance Tool -> Leaks. This will open an app called Instruments that will help you find the problem. See the Instruments documentation for more details.